# Data conditioning of google gmails/email addresses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to make filters for gmail and I need to get the sent TO emails.
The problem is that the emails in the To line of the email can have many different formats. I wanted to see if there was an easier way than what I was doing to unify the formats of the emails. I was just going to account for every case I could find and deal with like that.

```
function getTo(email) { 
// Logs the To lines of up to the first 1-500 emails in your Inbox 
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 75);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var emailto = messages[j].getTo();
        //runs the .to emails through the data conditioning function
        //emailprocess(email,emailto)
        }
        Logger.log(emailto);
    }
}



function main () {
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
getTo(email)
// createToFilte(toAddress, labelName)
}
    

function emailprocess(email,emailto){
var emailto = emailto.toLowerCase();
        switch (emailto) {
            case email:
                label = 0;
                break;
            case "john doe <johndoe@gmail.com>":
                label = 0;
                break;
            case "<johndoe@gmail.com>":
                label = 0 ;
                break;
            default:
                label = emailto.replace('johndoe+', '');
                label = label.replace("@gmail.com","")
                break;
        }
}
```

The emails can be in many different formats here are some:

- john doe < johndoe@gmail.com >
- johndoe@gmail.com
- < johndoe@gmail.com >
- johndoe@gmail.com , janedoe@gmail.com
- johndoe+65@gmail.com

and maybe only a little more.
Any help would be great. I am also not the best programmer so any way to make this more streamlined would be great.

Solution:

```
function getTo(email) {
var emailregex = /([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+)/gm  
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 500); // Logs the To lines of up   to the first 1-500 emails in your Inbox 
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var emailto = messages[j].getTo()
        var emailto = emailto.toLowerCase();
        //Logger.log(emailto);
        emailto = emailto.match(emailregex); //runs the .to emails through    the data conditioning
      Logger.log(emailto);
      if(emailto != null){
        for (var k = 0; k < emailto.length; k++) {
            if (emailto[k].indexOf("+") > -1) {
                var labelto = emailto[k].slice(emailto[k].indexOf("+") + 1,       emailto[k].indexOf("@"));
                createToFilter(emailto[k], labelto)
                Logger.log(emailto[k]);
                Logger.log(labelto);
            }

        }
      }
      

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an email regex (there are many out there), here is one example:

```
function getTo(email) { 
var emailregex =  /([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+)/gm
// Logs the To lines of up to the first 1-500 emails in your Inbox 
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 75);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var emailto = messages[j].getTo().match(emailregex);
        //runs the .to emails through the data conditioning function
        //emailprocess(email,emailto)
        }
        Logger.log(emailto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i was able to get it to work with your regex. Thank you again. This saved me from learning regex.